# set some text after input with name input via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

hi there I have a code like this:

```
<input name="name1" type="text"/>
<div class="error"></div>

<input name="name2" type="text"/>
<div class="error"></div>

<input name="name3" type="text"/>
<div class="error"></div>
```

I want set some text in div elements via JQuery.
for example fill `<div class="error"></div>` after 'name3'

Comment: What is `[name=firstName]` doing here if you were going to address the div?

Comment: @nicael you are right. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case use `next()`.

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[name="name3"]').next('.error').text("Hello");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="name1" type="text"/>
<div class="error"></div>

<input name="name2" type="text"/>
<div class="error"></div>

<input name="name3" type="text"/>
<div class="error"></div>
```

Comment: @nicael What do you mean. OP posted a question. I gave a tentative ans. Later he edited the question. I gave him the approach my this ans has and later I realised that my other answer was unnecessary and so I edited it off and created a demo of the current approach. I don't think I am wrong

Comment: No, you aren't wrong! I mean you edited your answer in grace period after OP edited their question, and I didn't notice that and posted the answer, [which I deleted immediately](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OK2Yx.png).